# Are there any German Internet slang acronyms like "LOL"?

Tags: slang

LOL (an acronym for "laughing out loud"), LMAO, ROTFL and other Internet slang acronyms that express bodily reactions, in particular laughter, are very popular.

Are there equivalent or similar German expressions? If they do exist, are they actually being used?

TIA ;-)

Comment: kA, s. 

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Abk%C3%BCrzungen_%28Netzjargon%29

Comment: @thei thx. HDGDL

Comment: LOL isn't German? I always thought it stands for "Lautes Online-Lachen". :)

Comment: by the way: Most of the English acronyms are used in German online conversations as well.

Comment: @musiKk LOL = "laughing out loud" was ja vom prinzip her dasselbe heisst, sobald du dann aber erweiterst: lmao, rofl, roflmao ... wirds vom deutschen her schwierig

Comment: @Vogel612: Whooooooosh.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's an (incomplete) list of German language internet acronyms. Only one of them expresses a bodily reaction:

- BD - Bis dann
- BG - Breites Grinsen
- DAU - Dümmster anzunehmender User (cf. Luser)
- HGW - Herzlichen Glückwunsch
- IDA / IEA  - Ich dich (euch) auch
- ILD - Ich liebe dich
- HDL - Hab' dich lieb
- HDGDL - Hab' dich ganz doll lieb
- kA - keine Ahnung (anglc.: keine Angabe)
- kwT -  Kein weiterer Text (also kT, oT, owT)
- LG - Liebe Grüße (also Viele Grüße, Viele liebe Grüße)
- mMn - Meiner Meinung nach
- SuFu - Suchfunktion
- WD - Wieder da
- WE - Wochenende

(an extract from [WP:Liste von Abkürzungen (Netzjargon)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Abk%C3%BCrzungen_%28Netzjargon%29))

But it's very popular to to set the [*inflektiv*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv) in asterisks to express one of those. This kind of speech is of course, as in English, considered childish and may even be impolite.

- *grins*, *lach*, *wein*, *aufsteh*, *rausgeh*, *rasenmäh*.

Comment: \*Schenkel-klopf-und-lachend-auf-dem-Boden-roll\*

Comment: used among younger people is also hdl = hab dich lieb.

Comment: Never saw VLG, but rather just LG (Liebe Grüße / Lieben Gruß). Though I never understood why anyone would need acronyms ;)

Comment: How "bis dann" shows body reaction?

Comment: +1 für den DAU :-)

Comment: very comprehensive and good list! I'd add MfG and *gg* (for 'grinse, grins', male use that too!). Also a lot of the english acronyms are used (everybody nows lol & rofl).

Comment: you could add special german creations like `afklo`, which is built by `afk` and `klo` (slang for toilet), meaning you're leaving to wash your hands.

Comment: @SamuelHerzog: sorry to tell you but gg is too much "good game" to be used as "grins", where you can easily make an emoticon, while mfg of course only makes sense in german. ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 no need to be sorry, we are talking about german acronyms, *gg* is english and used in two ways (as far as I know): good game, popular in the online gaming community e.g. wc3, LoL, DotA, SC and so on, but also as "\*gg\*" (giggle giggle) by girls in regular chatting (online chat rooms, skype, icq, msn). In a solely german game context I have never seen gg, but in german chat context you'll find \*gg\* as acronym for "grins (grins)"

Comment: @SamuelHerzog i am not a girl, so *giggle giggle* is not really my line. also i have yet to see a pure-german chat in online communities. even there gg might also mean good game but sarcastically when speaking of games or problems (gg Riot -> f*ck you Riot) note: Riot is the publisher of League of Legends

Comment: @Vogel612 The question was about German Internet Slang and not about German Internet Slang in Gaming Communities. You have to factor in every possible usage of Slang in Online Communities. Including but not limited to: Gaming Communities, Forums, Online Chat, Facebook, and so on. Additionally there are pure german online gaming communities, an example coming to mind are only-german browsergames. Please always think about the question and not about your personal experience only. In browsergame context good game would also make little sense since a lot of them are not round-based.

Comment: Fallen die in Deinem letzten Absatz beschriebenen Formen nicht unter [Inflektiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv)? In dem Artikel werden auch andere Aspekte der Zwischen-Sternchen-Schreibweise kurz behandelt...

Comment: Sind nicht die meisten davon in der SMS-Welt, also außerhalb des Internets entstanden? DAU lasse ich gelten, und kwT, welches ich selbst (bei heise.de) in die Welt gesetzt habe.

Comment: hdgdlbaedwuwz also existed.

Answer (score -1):

In countries where "u" is pronounced "oo" (and not "ew"), one thing which I slipped up on at first was

**Ups!** (= Oops!)

(Note that this is not an acronym, but still slang.)

This seems painfully obvious when one knows, but beforehand, while reading an IRC transcript for example, one may think that something appeared above (up) in the log which people are referring to.

Seems worthwhile to point out, although YMMV.

Comment: It's neither an acronym, nor internet-specific. I'm not even convinced it's "slang". *Ups* is a common German interjection that has probably been used in spoken and written language for decades, comparably to "hoppla", "huch", "aua", etc.