# What does "LG" mean?

Tags: meaning, valediction

In a general sense what does it mean when someone ends their text with the abbreviation LG followed by the first letter of their name?

Example:

> Um welche Uhrzeit am Morgen wird er den Zug nehmen?
>
> LG A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any German Internet slang acronyms like "LOL"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/662/are-there-any-german-internet-slang-acronyms-like-lol)

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/LG

Comment: http://www.der-postillon.com/2016/02/lg-electronics-verbietet-verwendung-von.html

Comment: I really hate “LG” abbreviating *Liebe Grüße*. That’s just domineering German of its abilities. Please just go back to use *Liebe Grüße*.

Comment: My german teacher once said: "If you don't have time to write out the full complimentary close you don't really mean it." The only exception I would make is when using your phone.

Comment: "That’s just domineering German of its abilities." @dakab, can you say that in German or English, please?

Answer (score 19):

*LG* is an abbreviation for *Liebe Grüße*, and mainly used if you only have very little time or space (like text messages) to write an actual valediction.

You might also come across:

- *MfG* -- *Mit freundlichen Grüßen*
- *VG* -- *Viele Grüße*

Comment: One should notice that you shouldn't use "MfG" unless you are texting. It is very impolitely not to spell greeting in full in a formal context.

Comment: @kay: Well, "MfG" is commonplace in e-mails in the business world, but indeed mostly restricted to people who already know each other.

Answer (score 3):

As mwil.me says, LG is just "Liebe Grüße". I have seen it in cases where lack of time or space seems very unlikely (say, an otherwise quite substantive email), and believe that some people simply always use that line so they don't have to think about different greetings for different levels of politeness/social distance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm german :D

- you can use "Liebe Grüße"(LG), if you write to a friend or family
- you can use "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" (MFG), if it's a professional mail to a person you have never seen
- you can use "Viele Grüße" (VG), if you're an extrovert person you can use it every time :D but mainly to buddies or workmates

VG :P

Comment: Don't write *u* instead of *you*.

Comment: Furthermore, you’re statements don’t seem more true if you add ":D". (Actually the opposite is true...)

Answer (score 0):

LG means 
Liebe Grüße in german

Comment: The answer doesn't add anything to what has been said in other answers.

Comment: Wenn die gleiche Antwort schon gegeben wurde, dann sollte man diese mit dem Pfeil nach oben als gut markieren, nicht die gleiche Antwort nochmal in eigenen Worten zufügen. Das verschwendet nur die Zeit der Leute, die sich schon mal mit der Frage befasst haben.